# Can't run playbook with root user for remote host

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run simple playbook for remote host(webserver1).

playbook

```
-
 name: "This is service play"
 hosts: webserver1
 tasks:
  -
   name: "start apache2 service"
   service:
     name: apache2
     state: started #stopped
```

Getting below error -

```
root@kubemaster:/etc/ansible/playbook/modules/service# ansible-playbook apache2.yml
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/inventory/inventory.txt with ini plugin: /etc/ansible/inventory/inventory.txt:12: Section [all_servers:children] includes
undefined group: sql_servers
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/inventory/inventory.txt as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

PLAY [This is service play] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [webserver1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Permission denied, please try again.", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
webserver1                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

My inventory file -

```
root@kubemaster:/etc/ansible/playbook/modules/service# cat ../../../inventory/inventory.txt
webserver1 ansible_host=192.168.1.12 ansible_ssh_pass=sneha ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 ansible_user=root
sqlserver1 ansible_host=192.168.1.11 ansible_ssh_pass=sneha ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 ansible_user=ahens

[web_servers]
websever1

[sql_server]
sqlserver1

[all_servers:children]
web_servers
sql_servers
```

I tried -

1. SSH access for the root user,  editing the **`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`** file and change the **`PermitRootLogin` **and **`PasswordAuthentication`** option to `yes` and restarted the SSH service on remote host.
2. Checked the firewall rules - They are inactive on remote host. (Also tried to active the firewall and allow ssh service.)
3. Tried connecting to the remote host manually using SSH to verify that the credentials are correct. Credentials are correct but can't login to remote host using ssh with root. (Default username is ahens and I can login through ssh without root.)

   Root login

   ```
   root@kubemaster:~# ssh root@192.168.1.12
   root@192.168.1.12's password:
   Permission denied, please try again.
   root@192.168.1.12's password:
   Permission denied, please try again.
   ```

   ahens login

   ```
   root@kubemaster:~# ssh ahens@192.168.1.12
      ahens@192.168.1.12's password:
      Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-69-generic x86_64)

       * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
       * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
       * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

        System information as of Sun Apr  2 03:30:24 PM UTC 2023

        System load:              0.1884765625
        Usage of /:               69.6% of 8.02GB
        Memory usage:             18%
        Swap usage:               0%
        Processes:                133
        Users logged in:          1
        IPv4 address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
        IPv4 address for enp0s3:  192.168.1.12
        IPv6 address for enp0s3:  3ffe:501:ffff:100:a00:27ff:fe28:5a6e

       * Strictly confined Kubernetes makes edge and IoT secure. Learn how MicroK8s
         just raised the bar for easy, resilient and secure K8s cluster deployment.

         https://ubuntu.com/engage/secure-kubernetes-at-the-edge

       * Introducing Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications.
         Receive updates to over 25,000 software packages with your
         Ubuntu Pro subscription. Free for personal use.

           https://ubuntu.com/pro

      Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

      28 updates can be applied immediately.
      To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

      Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
      See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status


      Last login: Sun Apr  2 14:14:49 2023 from 192.168.1.13
      ahens@kubeworker:~$
   ```
4. Tried ping and its working.

   ```
   root@kubemaster:/etc/ansible/playbook/modules/service# ping webserver1
   PING webserver1 (192.168.1.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from webserver1 (192.168.1.12): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.12 ms
   64 bytes from webserver1 (192.168.1.12): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.97 ms
   64 bytes from webserver1 (192.168.1.12): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.97 ms
   64 bytes from webserver1 (192.168.1.12): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=3.01 ms
   64 bytes from webserver1 (192.168.1.12): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=2.95 ms
   --- webserver1 ping statistics ---
   5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4010ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.969/2.802/3.121/0.421 ms
   ```

   Please someone tell me what is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all do not use ansible with root user directly, always use `become`.

You might have your root user locked since You can not login with it(if You are sure credential is okay).

From your `webserver1` host run `sudo passwd -S root`. it will show You something like:

```
$ sudo passwd -S root
root L 04/02/2023 0 99999 7 -1
```

`L` means user is locked and you need to unlock it.
You can do it using `sudo usermod -U root` or simply by setting a new password for root user with `sudo passwd root`.

If this does not fix your problem, i'd suggest to check `/var/log/auth.log` file and check the failure reason.

Comment: Thank you very much, My root user was locked i checked.  I tried your solution but it did not work at first so i unlocked the root user and changed the password. After that i restarted the `sshd` service.  And it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Check the if the root user is in denyuser list in the file  /etc/ssh/sshd_config file . If so, remove the root user from the deny user list and restart the SSH service on the remote host.

Answer (score -1):

Your inventory file has some misprints:

- web_server[s]
- webse[r]ver1

Try this one:

```
[web_servers]
webserver1 ansible_host=192.168.1.12 ansible_ssh_pass=sneha ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 ansible_user=root

[sql_servers]
sqlserver1 ansible_host=192.168.1.11 ansible_ssh_pass=sneha ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 ansible_user=ahens

[all_servers:children]
web_servers
sql_servers
```